# Trying to figure out the definition of JSX.Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to make use of a `JSX.Element` within a React application. The compiler is unhappy though.

I have two files `Main.tsx` and `EmployeeMask.js`. For some reason I am not sure of I cannot use EmployeeMask in its JSX form `<EmployeeMask />` as it is not understood as a JSX component.

Here is my `Main.tsx` file:

```
export interface MainProps {}

export interface MainState {}

export class Main extends React.Component<MainProps, MainState> {
    public constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
    }

    private maskChooser(): JSX.Element {
        return <EmployeeMask />;
    }

    public render() {
        return <div>
            {this.maskChooser()}
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Here is my `EmployeeMask.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';

export class EmployeeMask extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                EmployeeMask
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

The compiler tells me the following though:

```
(alias) class EmployeeMask
import EmployeeMask
'EmployeeMask' cannot be used as a JSX component.
  Its instance type 'EmployeeMask' is not a valid JSX element.
    Type 'EmployeeMask' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, refsts(2786)
```

I already tried adding `export default EmployeeMask;`, but this did not change anything.

Why does the compiler not recognize this as a `JSX.Element`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer and wanted to post it here in case someone has had the same problem. I found [this online TypeScript to JavaScript transpiler](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) in which I could transpile a working TypeScript class into JavaScript in order to compare and find out what was the problem before.

Diffing the result with what I had showed that the import was the problem.

```
import React from 'react';
```

instead of

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

Correcting this by adding "* as " solves the problem and makes the class usable.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be calling `<EmployeeMask />`, but the exported component's name is EmployeeMask2, which means it should be called like `<EmployeeMask2 />`.

This happens because it is a regular export (`export class` instead of `export default class`), so when you import it, you have to use something like `import {EmployeeMask2} from '<path>/EmployeeMask.js'`.

If you used a default export, you could call it however you want in your file, like:

`import Whatever from '<path>/EmployeeMask.js'`

Comment: I corrected the code. The "2" had nothing to do there. I also tried to change it to 'export default class` without any change. The error message is the absolute same.